# Restricting access to a user's chat activity.

Tags: discussion, feature-request, users

It appears I am able to see anyone's chat activity for the last 24 hours and at a coarser resolution for the past week (at least in The DMZ). I think it would be prudent to restrict access to this information.

Revision: I was specifically refering to a user's chat profile, the usercard, activity stats, user-historgram for 24-hour period and week.

Answer (score 2):

Well in fact confidentiality is a major problem, but chats are just not designed for this. I mean even IRC is monitored, saved by many users etc.

For the confidentiality,  all content posted by user on SE services are published under CC-by-sa. Maybe it could be stated somewhere to let people be aware of this.

Anyway, all request for private user talks / rooms etc has been denied. So I bet you would have hard time to support your suggestion. But maybe with proper argument. Even though I bet the major counter-argument will be that SE is not meant to address those needs : the philosophy is to be content-open. Introducing privacy in chat would spread like: "And why not make question/answer private too".

That will not be profitable I my opinion.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge (I havent done this lately so it may have changed), anyone can create a private room, and restrict access to it. That said, this is still not real confidentiality, but it is possible.